# How do you implement DI for IConfiguration in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, configuration, asp.net-core-6.0

I've been following the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#access-configuration-with-dependency-injection-di) and I've tried to enchance my codebase like the following:

```cs
public class GRequestModel(IConfiguration config) => _config = config;
{
    private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    public string path { get; set; }
    public string secret { get; set; }
    public string response { get; set; }
    public string remoteip { get; set; }

    public GRequestModel(string res, string remip)
    {
        response = res;
        remoteip = remip;
        var secret = Configuration["GoogleRecaptchaV3:Secret"];
        var path = Configuration["GoogleRecaptchaV3:ApiUrl"];
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(secret) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
        {
            //Invoke logger
            throw new Exception(
                "Invalid 'Secret' or 'Path' properties in appsettings.json. " + 
                "Parent: GoogleRecaptchaV3.");
        }
    }
}
```

But I keep getting a lot of errors if I do it like it's written in the documentation...

To clarify - my goal is to read the secret and API URL from appsettings.json and use this to set the values for Google's reCAPTCHA v3.

I need to do this because I want to migrate my web app to a stable version of .NET 6.

Comment: Is `public class GRequestModel(IConfiguration config) => _config = config` even valid C#? I'm not fully up-to-date with the latest C# 9's features, but that doesn't seem like one of them.

Comment: @Llama well, it's in the official documentation...

Comment: Can you point out where I can find it? I can't see it.

Comment: @Llama it's the only link in the question, but I'll link it here again: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#access-configuration-with-dependency-injection-di

Comment: That link shows `public class Service {`, it doesn't show `public class Service(IConfiguration config) => _config = config` ... It simply shows an expression-bodied [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors). You can see more about expression-bodied members [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members).

Comment: @Llama Oh, I thought that's how you "expand" my codebase. My bad. How should I add that required functionality then?

Comment: I would expect your code to look like `public GRequestModel(IConfiguration config, string res, string remip)`

Comment: @Llama I tried that too, didn't seem to work out :/ But maybe I made some mistakes

Comment: Are `res` and `remip` meant to be parameters you pass in?

Comment: @Llama yes, it's the remote IP and the response which gets evaluated in the further code

Comment: Well even if `GRequestModel(IConfiguration config) => _config = config;` is valid in latest c#, you never use _config and the Configuration is also never set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the syntax you have is wrong. Dependency injection should be done through the constructor (although some IoC containers provide property injection too):

```cs
public class GRequestModel
{
    public string path { get; set; }
    public string secret { get; set; }
    public string response { get; set; }
    public string remoteip { get; set; }

    public GRequestModel(IConfiguration configuration, string res, string remip)
    {
        response = res;
        remoteip = remip;
        var secret = configuration["GoogleRecaptchaV3:Secret"];
        var path = configuration["GoogleRecaptchaV3:ApiUrl"];
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(secret) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
        {
            //Invoke logger
            throw new Exception("Invalid 'Secret' or 'Path' properties in appsettings.json. Parent: GoogleRecaptchaV3.");
        }
    }
}
```

Now we're accepting `IConfiguration` in the correct place, we can address how to create this object and get `IConfiguration` from the container. To do this, I'm going to create a delegate in the same `GRequestModel` class:

```cs
public class GRequestModel
{
    public delegate GRequestModel Factory(string res, string remip);
```

Then we can register this factory with the container:

```cs
services.AddTransient<GRequestModel.Factory>(serviceProvider => 
     (string res, string remip) => new GRequestModel(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>(), res, remip));
```

Now you can inject `GRequestModel.Factory` and create a `GRequestModel` using it:

```cs
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public SomeOtherClass(GRequestModel.Factory grequestFactory)
    {
        GRequestModel grm = grequestFactory("resValue", "remipValue");
    }
}
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8c6lsS)

---

Edit: In response to your comment about it being more complicated than the documentation, that's because your use case is more complicated than the documentation examples. Specifically, you want to accept parameters `res` and `remip`.

Consider this example:

```cs
public class MyService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public MyService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
       _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void DoSomething(string res, string remip)
    {
        string configValue = _configuration["myConfigKey"];
    }
}
```

You can register this and use this like so:

```cs
services.AddTransient<MyService>();

public class MyOtherClass
{
    public MyOtherClass(MyService service)
    {
        service.DoSomething("resValue", "remipValue");
    }
}
```

This is much simpler because you don't also need to inject the parameters into the constructor. It really depends on what you're trying to do as to which is the best option.

Comment: Wow, it's more complicated than the documentation makes it look... Also, I'm getting this error while implementing: `Error CS0103: The name 'grequestFactory' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: It's more complicated than the documentation makes it look because you're want to instantiate `GRequestModel` with _parameters_ (`res`, and `remip`).  If `GRequestModel` was just a service that accepted `IConfiguration` without the other two parameters, and then had a method that accepted `res` and `remip` and did some work there, then you could simply have registered it with `services.AddTransient<GRequestModel>` and then injected it as `public SomeOtherClass(GRequestModel grModel)`. It's the parameters that have made this more complex.

Comment: Clearly the error you're getting is a typo. Please look closely at `SomeOtherClass` again.

Comment: I managed to fix it, but now the whole backend logic still gives me 404 for the POST request for this logic, but I think it's beyond the scope of this question, I'll just open a new one. Thank you!

Comment: @Munchkin I've added a secondary example of how it might work without injecting `res` and `remip` into the constructor. It depends if you want to construct an object that has `res` and `remip` as values that it holds, or if they're just relevant to a method call (in which case you can just pass them to the method).